# Enhance a MarianMT pretrained model from HuggingFace with more training data

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am using a pretrained MarianMT machine translation model from [English to German](https://huggingface.co/Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-de). I also have a large set of high quality English-to-German sentence pairs that I would like to use to enhance the performance of the model, which is trained on the OPUS corpus, but **without** making the model *forget* the OPUS training data. Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Did you give a look at the [documentation on how to fine-tune](https://huggingface.co/transformers/training.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the finetune.sh script shown [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/seq2seq/finetune.sh)? In addition to the short list of CLI flags listed there, you could try adding:

```
--src_lang "en" \
--tgt_lang "de" \
--num_train_epochs 400 \
--warmup_steps 20 \
--train_batch_size 32 \
--eval_batch_size 32 \
--data_dir "/data/dir" \
--output_dir "/path/to/store/model/etc" \
--cache_dir "/path/for/misc/files" \
--max_source_length 128 \
--max_target_length 128 \
--val_max_target_length 128 \
--test_max_target_length 128 \
--model_name_or_path "</path/to/pretrained>"
```

where the "/path/to/pretrained" could be either a local path on your machine or MarianMT model (Opus-en-de or equivalent). The "data/dir" has a "train.source" and "train.target" for the source & target languages, such that line number x of the target is a translation of line x in the source (and same with "val.source" and "val.target"). I have changed the finetune.py script [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/77cd0e13d2d09f60d2f6d8fb8b08f493d7ca51fe/examples/seq2seq/finetune.py#L415) to

```
parser = TranslationModule.add_model_specific_args(parser, os.getcwd())
```

and then ran the finetune.sh script.

Note: The gradients blew up when I used the "fp16" flag (with Pytorch 1.6), so I had removed it. Also, you might want to check on the "val_check_interval", "check_val_every_n_epoch", and probably check [this issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3447) on how to save multiple checkpoints.

Answer (score 1):

I did the finetuning as described here: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/seq2seq#translation

To train the model (fr to de) and do evaluation at the end:
python examples/seq2seq/run_translation.py --do_train True  --do_eval True  --model_name_or_path Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-de-fr  --source_lang de   --target_lang fr   --source_prefix "translate German to French: "   --train_file ../data/translations-train-de-fr1.json  --validation_file  ../data/translations-val-de-fr1.json   --output_dir ../tst-translation-models   --per_device_train_batch_size=4   --per_device_eval_batch_size=4 --overwrite_output_dir True --predict_with_generate True --fp16 True

The trained model gets stored into the folder: tst-translation-models

Using the finetuned model to do evaluation only:
folder use 'copy_mode.sh', which must be adapted per language):
python examples/seq2seq/run_translation.py --do_train False  --do_eval True  --model_name_or_path ../tst-translation-models --source_lang de   --target_lang fr   --source_prefix "translate German to French: "   --validation_file  ../data/translations-val-de-fr1.json --per_device_eval_batch_size=4 --predict_with_generate True --fp16 True

Regards, Felix

PS: Note that the training and valudation data must be in the following form (one such entry per row):
{ "translation": { "de": "Freilegung der Leitung (durch VN installiert)", "fr": "Dégagement de la conduite (installée par le PA)" } }